# Accessing values from laravel Many to Many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, pivot

I have two tables doctors and specializations and a pivot table doctor_specialities.

In Doctor model, I have defined relationship like this-

```
public function specializations(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Specialization', 'doctor_specialities', 'speciality_id', 'doctor_id');
}
```

And in the Specialization model, the relationship is like this-

```
public function doctors(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Doctor', 'doctor_specialities', 'speciality_id', 'doctor_id');
}
```

I am getting all the doctors of a specialization like this-

```
$doctors = Specialization::find($request->specialization)->doctors
                            ->where('city_id', $request->city);
```

It's working fine. I am getting the correct output.

But now I want to print all the specializations of each doctor but it is returning an empty array.

```
foreach ($doctors as $doctor) {
    var_dump($doctor->specializations);
}
```

The output I'm getting is-

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)[218]
  protected 'items' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

How can I print specializations of each doctor??

Comment: Can you let us know the relationship-methods you have defined on the Doctor and Specialization models for the many-to-many relationship? Also post the table name of the pivot and the underlying columns. You can double check if they are correct from the Documentation.

Comment: updated my question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your updated question, while defining the specializations relation on the Doctor model, the third argument is the foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the relationship (Doctor in your case), while the fourth argument is the foreign key name of the model that you are joining to (Specialization). The relationship should be defined as follows:

```
public function specializations(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Specialization', 'doctor_specialities', 'doctor_id', 'speciality_id');
}
```

Please refer the [documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you are getting a single doctor? how is it possible to get single doctor while querying for Specialization?

```
$specialization = Specialization::find($request->specialization)->doctors
                        ->where('city_id', $request->city);
```

i guess you are not clear about what you are trying to achieve?

if you want doctors of a particular specialization you should do this;

```
    $specialization = Specialization::with(['doctors' => function ($query) {
                             $query->where('city_id', $request->city);
                         }])->find( $request->specialization);
```

and loop through doctors

```
foreach($specialization->doctors as $doctor){
do what ever you want
}
```

Comment: Actually, the actual result from database is a single doctor. Whenever I'll add more doctors to database I will get more. Now I want to access each specializations of a doctor. But I'm getting empty array.

Comment: can you add code from your controller where you are querying and your relationships in specialization and doctor models?